# What about the converse of this statement?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

A subgroup $C$ of a group $G$ is said to be a characteristic subgroup of $G$ if and only if $T[C] \subset C$ for all automorphisms $T$ of $G$.

Here $T[C] \colon= \{ T(c) \colon c \in C \}$ is the image of set $C$ under the mapping $T$.

I can show that every characteristic subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Does the converse hold too? If so, how to prove it? If not, what counter-example can be given?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup#Characteristic_vs._normal) page gives several counterexamples.

Answer (score 3):

Converse is true when $Inn(G)=Aut(G)$,

as an example it true for $S_4$ as $Inn(S_4)= Aut(S_4)\cong S_4$ and $A_4$ and $V_4$ are both normal and characteristic subgroup of $S_4$.

In general it is not true, being characteristic is stronger than being normal.

Smallest such example $G=K_4\cong Z_2 \times Z_2$, even if every subgroup is normal, it has no 
nontrivial characteristic subgroup.

Comment: What is meant by Inn($G$) and Aut($G$)? And how to verify your statements about $S_4$?

Comment: $Aut(G)$ is set of all isomorphism from $G$ to $G$, and $Inn(G)$ is 
all automorphism constructed by conjugation, in general $Inn(G)\leq Aut(G)$ , please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup#Characteristic_vs._normal) for examples and a nice brief discussion.